# Why does the following code does not move the div towards left

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Why does the test div not moving towards left even after applying the window.setinterval function ?
It just shows me the div after i click the Start the animation button.

```
<body>
<div id="test">
It is just a test content
</div>
<button onclick="animate();">Start the animation</button>
<button onclick="sto();">Stop the animation</button>
<script>
var timeoutId;
var currentpos=0;
document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor="black";
document.getElementById('test').style.height="400px";
document.getElementById('test').style.width="300px";
document.getElementById('test').style.boxSizing="border-box";
document.getElementById('test').style.display="none";
function animate(){
    window.setTimeout(show,2000);
}
function show()
{
document.getElementById('test').style.left="0px";
document.getElementById('test').style.display="block";
timeoutId=window.setInterval(start,50);
}
function start()
{
    currentpos+=5;
    document.getElementById("test").style.left=currentpos + "px";
}
function sto()
{
    window.clearInterval(timeoutId);
}
</script>
```

Comment: because you are not setting its [css position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the position of element.

```
document.getElementById("test").style.position = "absolute";
```

Also, **fixed** and **relative** are other possible values of css position property.

Comment: fixed is also a possible value that can be used

Comment: yes, but applying fixed makes element not to scroll. It is purposely used in some scenarios where user want to fix the elements at a paticular position even page gets scrolled

Comment: That is beyond the point, the way your answer is stated makes it seem like there are only two possible values that allow you to change an elements position. There is also nothing in the question stating what kind of positioning the user wants so for all we know they could want a fixed positioned element.